# How to get all rows based on characteristics of one column? SQL

Tags: sql

I need to get all the claim rows based on procedure 900. My example is below. If I put a WHERE filter I wont get the 'procedure 600' row on claim 1.

| claim | procedure |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 900 |
| 1 | 600 |
| 2 | 500 |
| 2 | 600 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN <subquery>`. For example:

```
select *
from t
where claim in (select claim from t where procedure = 900)
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Just don't try doing this with aliased names.